# I have a node application which can able to automatically send a mail when a user is register. But the problem is the message is reach as spam

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have made a node application which can able to send a mail when an account is created by a user. But the problem is the mail is reaching at the user as spam. How to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the recipient's mail server. The spam filter recognizes the mail as spam. To solve the problem, the sender address must be whitelisted on the recipient's mail server.